# How could i use the routing in reactjs to redirect from one page after loading to another url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, redux, react-redux

Now I use routing like this:

```
<Route path='/main' component={App1}>
  <Route path='/main/:id' component={App2}>
    <Route path='/main/:id/basic' component={App3}/>
    <Route path='/main/:id/page1' component={App4}/>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

But how can i use something like this:

```
<Route path='/main' component={App1}>
  <Route path='/main/:id' component={App2, App3} />
  <Route path='/main/:id/page1' component={App4}/>
</Route>
```

or ***better*** this:

```
<Route path='/main' component={App1}>
  <Route path='/main/:id' component={App2, App3}>
    <Route path='/main/:id/basic' component={App3}/>
    <Route path='/main/:id/page1' component={App4}/>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Or redirect from `/main/:id` page to `/main/:id/basic` page after loading component `App2`, because i should load components `App2` (first) and `App3` (second) by opening `/main/:id` url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using React Router 3. In this case use `<IndexRedirect>` component to achieve your goal:

```
<Route path='/main' component={App1}>
  <Route path='/main/:id' component={App2}>
    <IndexRedirect to='basic' />
    <Route path='/main/:id/basic' component={App3}/>
    <Route path='/main/:id/page1' component={App4}/>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Also, there is no need to use full paths in nested routes, for `App3` and `App4`, so your code could be a bit simplified:

```
<Route path='/main' component={App1}>
  <Route path=':id' component={App2}>
    <IndexRedirect to='basic' />
    <Route path='basic' component={App3}/>
    <Route path='page1' component={App4}/>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

More info about redirects can be found [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md#index-redirects)

By the way, check out [version 4 of React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router). It was released recently and has bunch of nice features.

Answer (score 1):

one route path only can handle one component. you can still use current routes, so we will be redirect via component.

```
<Route path='/main' component={App1}>
  <Route path='/main/:id' component={App2}>
    <Route path='/main/:id/basic' component={App3}/>
    <Route path='/main/:id/page1' component={App4}/>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

if you re using react-router v3

in `App2` -> `componentDidMount` , add for example

```
this.context.router.push({ pathname: `/main/3/basic`})
```

or

```
browserHistory.push('/main/3/basic')
```

detail about navigatoing outside component https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md